# UILocalNotification Fires despite begin deleted

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, local, uilocalnotification

So I have implemented a UILocal Notification into my app:

```
UILocalNotification *LocalNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (LocalNotification == nil) return;
NSDate *execute = [[NSDate date]dateByAddingTimeInterval:10] ;
LocalNotification.fireDate = execute;
LocalNotification.alertBody = @"Check out what's new!";
LocalNotification.repeatInterval=NSDayCalendarUnit;


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:LocalNotification];
```

The Notification fired ok. However, I've noticed that it's firing every minute and displays old text (which I have since updated). So instead of saying "check out what's new," it displays an old string. I'm completely puzzled by this.  I even deleted the notification and it still fires. I've tried a clean build several times to no avail.  Any ideas how to change this notification to fire correctly and display the right string?

Comment: how did you delete the notification ?

Comment: That won't help, use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllNotification]`